# Eliminate unwanted characters from JSON file using different threads (Python)

Tags: python, json, multithreading, replace, python-multithreading

In my python file, I have created a class called `Download`. The code where the class is:

```
import requests, json, os, pytube, threading

class Download:


    def __init__(self, url, json=False, get=False, post=False, put=False, unwanted="", wanted="", unwanted2="", wanted2="", unwanted3="", wanted3=""):
        self.url = url
        self.json = json
        self.get = get
        self.post = post
        self.put = put
        self.unwanted = unwanted
        self.wanted = wanted
        self.unwanted2 = unwanted2
        self.wanted2 = wanted2
        self.unwanted3 = unwanted3
        self.wanted3 = wanted3 

    def downloadJson(self):
        if self.get is True:
            downloadJson = requests.get(self.url)
            downloadJson = str(downloadJson.content)
            downloadJsonS = str(downloadJson) # This saves the downloaded JSON file as string

            if self.json is True:
                with open("downloadedJson.json", "w") as writeDownloadedJson:
                    writeDownloadedJson.write(json.dumps(downloadJson))
                    writeDownloadedJson.close()

                with open("downloadedJson.json", "r") as replaceUnwanted:
                    a = replaceUnwanted.read()
                    x = a.replace(self.unwanted, self.wanted)
                    # y = a.replace(self.unwanted2, self.wanted2)
                    # z = a.replace(self.unwanted3, self.wanted3)
                    print(x)

                with open("downloadedJson.json", "w") as writeUnwanted:
                    # writeUnwanted.write(y)
                    # writeUnwanted.write(z)
                    writeUnwanted.write(x)

            else:
                # with open("downloadedJson.json", "w")as j:
                #     j.write(downloadJsonS)
                #     j.close()
                pass
```

I have written all this by myself, and I understand how it works. My objective is to remove all the unwanted characters that come in the JSON file once downloaded, such as: **\\n**, **\'** or **\n**. I have many arguments in the `__init__()` function, like the `__init__(unwanted="", wanted="", unwanted2="")` **etcetera.**

By this, when adding any character to the `unwanted` parameter, such as: **\\n**, it should replace all these characters by a space. This is done properly, and it works. The lines of code that are comments are the lines of code that I was using, but that did not work. It would only replace the characters from only **1** argument.

Is there any way of passing all the unwanted characters in each for each argument, using threads. If it is not possible using threads, is there any alternative?

By the way, the file where I am executing the class: (**main.py**):

```
from downloader import Download

with open("url.txt", "r")as url:
    x = Download(url.read(), get=True, json=True, unwanted="\\n")
    x.downloadJson()
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Probably you want to chain the replacements like `x=a.replace(self.unwanted, self.wanted)` then `y = x.replace(self.unwanted2, self.wanted2)` or just `a = a.replace(self.unwanted, self.wanted).replace(self.unwanted2, self.wanted2)`?

Comment: Yes thanks, I will try what you said :)

Comment: Yes! It worked. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the replacements one after another:

```
x = a.replace(self.unwanted, self.wanted)
x = x.replace(self.unwanted2, self.wanted2)
x = x.replace(self.unwanted3, self.wanted3)
```

You could also chain the replacement together, but that would quickly become hard to read:

```
x = a.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)
```

Btw, instead of having multiple `unwantedN` and `wantedN`,
it would be probably a lot easier to use a list of `(unwanted, wanted)` pairs, something like this:

```
def __init__(self, url, json=False, get=False, post=False, put=False, replacements=[]):
    self.url = url
    self.json = json
    self.get = get
    self.post = post
    self.put = put
    self.replacements = replacements
```

And then you could perform the replacements in a loop:

```
x = a
for unwanted, wanted in self.replacements:
    x = x.replace(unwanted, wanted)
```